# Unable to view dashboards on Spotfire Webplayer if connected from database

Tags: sql-server, spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I'm new with Spotfire and I'm trying to publish my spotfire dashboards. When I use excel and create the dashboards I'm able to view them on webplayer but when I connect spotfire to a database and create dashboards, I'm not able to view it on webplayer as it asks for username and password for the data source. I'm 100% sure I'm entering the correct credentials but it doesn't login and I'm stuck. I'm using MS Sql server studio 2017.

When uploading the data into the database I tried with windows authentication and also sql-server authentication but it doesn't seem to work. When I use windows authentication I used my windows login credentials and when I tried sql-server authentication I entered the same credentials which I used for login into the sql server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please find attached the image.[image]

Comment: you need to look at your server.log in /tss/tomcat/logs . also check sql.log. just to add: this is not a Spotfire problem; this is an SQL Server problem. chances are the machine that Spotfire Server is installed to does not have authorization to log in to the SQL Server, or SQL Server is not accepting connections from that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. It was a firewall issue which was blocking me from connecting to the database.